# how to settext() of an text area using list

Tags: java, swing

I have problem while learning java using netbean in java ui.
I have a string list that is called `ListTo`.
I have a `comboboxmodel` that contains an object. I have a `textarea` with variable name `to`, and I also have a button. If I click that button the text area will be like this
 `" a " <- first`
But the second time I click the button it will be like this
`"a , b "`
and so on every time I click the button.

Here's my code:

```
 contact = listCon.get(cbcon.getSelectedIndex() - 1);
    listTo.add(contact.getNamaContact());

        for (int i = 0; i < listTo.size(); i++) {
            if(i==listTo.size()-1){

            to.setText(listTo.get(i));
            }

        else{
                 to.setText(listTo.get(i)+", ");

                }

    }
```

When I click the button the text area only shows the last of the list.
For example when I first click the button the text area will be "a", and the second time the text area will be "b" **not** "a, b"
How do I get the text area to show all of list items that I have?

Comment: You should have a string, or `StringBuilder`, that is appended to in the for loop, then after the for loop use `setText(string)`. Your overwriting the contents of `to` with every call to `to.setText(...)`.

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setText().

Instead you can use the `append(...)` method of a `JTextArea` to append text to the existing text.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to *append* the extra text each time you call setText, so that you don't lose previous content.
eg: `to.setText( to.getText() +"," + listTo.get(i));`

You could clean it up a bit by storing this into a variable at the beginning of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can either replace `setText()` with `append()`.  Or (as others have suggested) create your String during the loop and then call `setText()` once at the end.